# Powerquery - Dynamic path setup

Tags: powerquery

I have setup a file with multiple queries. The users are expected to download the file from the server, save it onto their their own private folders, update the path field that has been setup as a table inside the excel workbook, and refresh the query and it should work.

The solution works fine on my machine. When i move the folder location to other folders, it also works fine. However when my staff do it, it does not seem to work. I am running a 64bit version of excel and staff are running a 32bit version. This is the only difference between our machines.

The source for the queries are worded as suchh : = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(Table1&"\PO.pdf"), [Implementation="1.3"])

The table1 is a drill down of the path which is entered by user into the excel table.

Below is the error message. Any suggestions on how to fix this will be greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: did you check the Query Options ? Security and Privacy...

Comment: How to check that?

Comment: Data ---> Get Data ---> at the bottom Query Options

Comment: and also try to refresh the queries in the edit mode and see if it gives any error...

Comment: [check this and lower all your privacy and security settings as much as you can - at your own risk](https://www.thepoweruser.com/2019/03/12/data-privacy-and-the-formula-firewall/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. It is simply to set the privacy level to None for both global and current workbook [image]